# How to change content of a modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am to create modals for ~20 charts. These charts must run permanently, as they record insulation values. They should be accessible by clicking on the controller(These are Displayed on the HTML).

All modals I found were specifically adapted to 1 element. Since I can't create an endless CSS, I don't know what to do.

My exact question now: How do I create a modal that can display different elements during runtime?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***>>>[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+reuse+modal+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Using JS you can manipulate any element of your DOM. A very basic example would be `document.getElementById('modal_main').innerText = "new modal text";` Is this what you're asking? And what do you mean by "create an endless CSS"? How does CSS relate to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the idea from the below code about how you can use 1 Pop up modal with dynamic content.

```js
$("li[data-target='#myModal']").on('click',function()
{
  $(".modal-body").html($(this).attr('data-content'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text1">Text1</li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text2">Text2</li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Content of Text3">Text3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more of search here is what worked for me:

```html
<div id="ID01" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content" style="width: 1250px; height: 850px;">
    <div class="w3-container" data-align="center">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('ID01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
      <div data-role="chart" data-file="xml/chart.xml" class="force-bottom" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px; top: 20px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div onclick="document.getElementById('ID01').style.display= 'block'">
```